# regular expression using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression `^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])\S*$` which indicates that the input should contain alphabets and can contain special characters or digits along with the alphabets. But it is not allowing white spaces since i have used \S.

Can some one suggest me a reg exp which should contain alphabets and it can contain digits or special characters and white space but alphabets are must and the last character should not end with a white space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z]).*$
```

Note that in JavaScript `.` doesn't match new lines, and there is no dot-all flag (`/s`). You can use something like `[\s\S]` instead if that is an issue:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*?[A-Za-z])[\s\S]*$
```

Since you only have a single lookahead, you can simplify the pattern to:

```
^.*[A-Za-z].*$
```

Or, even simpler:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

`[A-Za-z]` will match if it finds a letter anywhere in the string, you don't really need to search the rest from start to end.

---

To also validate the last character isn't a whitespace, it is probably easiest to use the lookahead again (as it basically means `AND` in regular expressions:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z]).*\S$
```

Comment: [A-Za-z] works but i also need a check so that the last character is not a space

Comment: @User -  `.*\S$` at the end of each patten can validate that: `[A-Za-z].*\S$`, for example. Can you please edit the question to add this requirement?

Comment: just one more thing, i am not able to assign ^.*[A-Za-z].*\S$ to a variable and then use it

Comment: @user - should be `var r = /^.*[A-Za-z].*\S$/;` - nothing special here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @user - Very true - it also doesn't work if the last character is the only letter. You can use the first one again: `^(?=.*?[A-Za-z]).*\S$`. I'll update the answer. You can also use `[A-Za-z].*\S$|[A-Za-z]$`, but it isn't as elegant as the first option.